# How to rename and bulk-import files from file system to SharePoint?

Tags: migration, library, file-system

We have files that are named like this:

```
AB0371v12 Client Standard Operating Procedure.docx
AC2110v2 Deliveries to Western Region.docx
RB2010 Facility Tours.pdf
```

I'm looking for a tool that will let me move each of these files from our current file system library into one of the document libraries of my choice in the site collection of my choice.

What are some tools that can do this which have favorable results?

Answer (score 2):

There are many Ways to handle this.

- If you are good in Powershell, as per you requirements, create a script which will get the source location and destination Library location as well as source file name and destination file.couple of examples here : [Link 1](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/618d52cf-4cef-4294-98e2-0501e86d84ff/file-renaming-for-sharepoint) [link2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/762291/Upload-Files-to-Library-in-SharePoint-using-PowerS)
- codeplex have a tools...[SharePoint Multiple File Upload Script](http://spfileupload.codeplex.com/) or [SPFileZilla = FileZilla for SharePoint](https://spfilezilla.codeplex.com/)
- If you looking 3rd party tool, [Sharegate's](http://en.share-gate.com/sharepoint-migration/features) tool I used in past and had very good success rate.

Answer (score 1):

Sharegate Migration tool allows migration of data from File System to be bulk moved to SharePoint.

The tool also has metadata editing capabilities which can be used to set to change file properties.

http://en.share-gate.com/

Answer (score 0):

There are a slew of options.

1. Powershell - gives you the most flexibility with what you want to do
2. 3rd party tools like Content Matrix from Metalogix, MetaVis from Metalogix amongst others
3. Server side code - create console apps to import the data for you, much like Powershell, gives you control over what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DMS-Shuttle for these purposes. DMS-Shuttle can upload folder structure with all documents to SharePoint. During uploading the tool can remove invalid charasters from file- and folder names. The list of invalid characters is configurable. There is a Trial verison: http://dms-shuttle.com/downloads/. For students and NGO's it is free. Disclaimer: I'm working for the Company.